# How to Highlight the selected item in listfragment?

Tags: android

I have several ListFragments . I wanted to Highlight the selected item on click. It should be highlighted when i am navigating through the next listfragment launched by clicking the item in previous listfragment. Please give some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code did the job for me.

OnOffListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.DYNAMICBACKLIGHTLIST);
        OnOffListView.setChoiceMode(1);

Answer (score 0):

Very simple..... try to use base adapter and based on the position set background color for that position.